# Google App Engine Standard の Ruby (beta) でデプロイができなくなった

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud, google-app-engine

昨日は問題なかったのですが、今日デプロイするとエラーになってしまい、起動できませんでした。
ソースへの変更等はしていません。
また別のRailsアプリケーション（別プロジェクトですが以前まではGAE上で動いていたもの）をデプロイしても同様のエラーとなってしまいました。

beta版なので変更が入ったのかな？と思いますが、どなたか解決方法をご存知でしたら教えてください。

ログはこちらです。

```
2019-12-11T03:50:36.531824Z bundler: failed to load command: rails (/srv/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/rails) A 
2019-12-11T03:50:36.531878Z Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find nokogiri-1.10.7 in any of the sources A 
2019-12-11T03:50:36.531897Z   /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:87:in `block in materialize' A 
2019-12-11T03:50:36.531913Z   /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:81:in `map!' A 
2019-12-11T03:50:36.531928Z   /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:81:in `materialize' A 
2019-12-11T03:50:36.531950Z   /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:170:in `specs' A 
2019-12-11T03:50:36.531968Z   /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:237:in `specs_for' A 
2019-12-11T03:50:36.531985Z   /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:226:in `requested_specs' A 
2019-12-11T03:50:36.532001Z   /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:108:in `block in definition_method' A 
2019-12-11T03:50:36.532015Z   /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup' A 
2019-12-11T03:50:36.532029Z   /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `setup' A 
2019-12-11T03:50:36.532047Z   /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>' A 
2019-12-11T03:50:36.532063Z   /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' A 
2019-12-11T03:50:36.532080Z   /opt/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' A
```

Comment: 補足ですが、flexible環境では正しく起動できます。

Comment: Container Registryを確認したところやはり新しいruby25のruntimeが昨日追加されていました。
Cloud Buildを見ても、今日のbuildから使われているImageが変わっているので、やはり原因はこれのようです。。
Googleに問い合わせてみます。

Comment: 私はこれとまったく同じ問題を抱えています。 英語のstackoverflowに関する問題を投稿し、解決策が見つかった場合はここで更新します。

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59292862/could-not-find-nokogiri-1-10-7-in-any-of-the-sources-for-ruby-standard-environme

Comment: 公式の回答からの引用：これは、今週公開されたApp Engine Ruby Runtimeリリースに関連しているようです。 問題の調査中にロールバックしています。 ロールバックは数時間以内に完了するはずです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
私も今deployするとCloud Buildで以前のバージョンであるruby25_20191020_2_5_7_RC00が使用されていることを確認しました。